# how to check 24c32 eprom is connected or not to arduino runtime?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, programming, eeprom

I want to check it on runtime if runitme i remove eprom then it shows "please insert dongle " also tried using while loop showing eroor.. How can i solve it?

```
Wire.beginTransmission(80);
      error = Wire.endTransmission();
    if (error == 0)
    {
    serial.print("connected");
    }
    else
    {
    serial.print("please insert dongle");
    }
```

also tried using while loop in loop()

```
void loop()
{
while (error == 0){
Serial.print("connected");
}

Serial.print("insert dongle");
}
```

Comment: Don't completely change the question and invalidate the existing answer. Also write properly. What is this: "*usin ehilw llop*"?

Comment: Did you try Wire.avaliable()?

Answer (score 0):

You should take parts of the [I2C Scanner](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner). You don't need to scan for all addresses - you can just scan for the one address you're interested in:

```
Wire.beginTransmission(80);
error = Wire.endTransmission();

if (error == 0)
{
  Serial.print("Connected");
} else {
  Serial.println("Insert dongle");
}
```

Comment: not working in runtime using also while loop? how to work as runtime?

Comment: Define "doesnt work"...